# Using group by in a sql query for remuving duplicates

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a query like this:

```
select 
o.Name,
o.Family,
o.phone,
o.OBJECTID,
o.owner_id,
l.Licence_Contex,
l.Licence_title,
l.Id 
from 
[dbo].[owner_licence] as l,[dbo].[OWNER] as o 
where o.[owner_id] =l.[Owner_ID] 
    And l.Id 
    NOT IN 
        (select l.id from [dbo].[owner_licence] as l,[dbo].[OWNER] as o 
        where o.[owner_id] =l.[Owner_ID] 
        And (l.Registration_date1  > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
        or l.[Registration_date2]> DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
        or l.[Registration_date3]> DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
        or l.[Registration_date4] > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
        or l.[Registration_date5]> DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate())))
```

the result is some how like this

```
john    smith   09305689220 1080199884  1   licencetitle_1  licencecontex_1 10
John    Smith   09305689220 1080199884  1   licencetitle_2 licencecontex3   13
```

As you can see the both of these rows are for the same person and I want to aggregate these duplicate persons into one row..Is there any way to do it?I useg group by o.owner_id and also distinct but they does not work..

Comment: You need some logic to aggregate them. What data do you want to sum? To take the maximum of? The minimum? average? Do you want to ignore any data? Which one? Why? P.S. your query is unreadable... Could you spend some time formatting it?

Comment: can you please format your query

Comment: Your welcome, Did my answer solved your issue if not please tell me.

Comment: @Ben I just want to filter rows that have same owner_id and just show a row for each of them

Comment: @Hardik Thanks,I left a comment in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery restricts the license to the one with the most maximum (qualified) id for each owner, so you should only get 1 license (and therefore 1 row) per owner.

```
select 
o.Name,
o.Family,
o.phone,
o.OBJECTID,
o.owner_id,
l.Licence_Contex,
l.Licence_title,
l.Id 
from 
[dbo].[owner_licence] as l
join [dbo].[OWNER] as o on o.[owner_id] = l.[Owner_ID]
join (select 
    max(ol.id) max_lid,
    ol.owner_id
from
    owner_licence ol
where ol.id not in (select l.id from [dbo].[owner_licence] as l,[dbo].[OWNER] as o 
        where o.[owner_id] =l.[Owner_ID] 
        And (l.Registration_date1  > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
        or l.[Registration_date2]> DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
        or l.[Registration_date3]> DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
        or l.[Registration_date4] > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
        or l.[Registration_date5]> DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate())))
group by
    ol.owner_id) t1 on t1.owner_id = o.owner_id AND t1.max_lid = l.id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this as one row then you will need to remove your last column from the the SElect clause.

Use Group by clause

Comment: There are 3 columns with different data and this certainly isn't the only option...

Comment: Thanks for your help..I did not get which column?l.Id ?If I remove this I can not use NOT IN

Comment: just remove l.id column from the select cluase it should work. is is giving you any error?

Comment: Please give me insert query if possible so that i can help you to resolve your issue

Comment: I removed l.id and it gives me again 2 rows..I tried FuzzyTree's method and it works great..Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have a complicated query.  Here is a way to do what you want:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select Name, Family, phone, OBJECTID, owner_id, Licence_Contex, Licence_title,
       max(Id) as id
from t
group by Name, Family, phone, OBJECTID, owner_id, Licence_Contex, Licence_title;
```

You need to `group by` all the columns *except* the one that has duplicates.  For that, you need to choose a value.  This query chooses the maximum value.

`Distinct` doesn't work because it applies to all rows in the `select`, including the `id` that has different values on different rows.

Comment: wow..my mitake..I had removed one of records ant it showed one record that time but now your method gives me again two records..FuzzyTree method works fine now